# Asterisk's "dialplan reload" and "help" commands are not found

Tags: asterisk

I've installed Asterisk 13(current) on CentOS7(without DAHDI/LIBPRI). It seems to work. I was following instructional videos, but at some point these use `dialplan reload` and `help` commands. These commands do not work for me.

Were they removed/replaced?
Also, if I use the <kbd>TAB</kbd> for command hints I see that `core restart` is there, but when I call it - it's not found also.

Comment: How did you do the install? Those commands *should* work...

Answer (score 1):

If you installed from source, I would recommend that that you make sure you ran `make samples` to start. This installs the conf files cli.conf, cli_aliases.conf, and cli_permissions.conf. This files are needed so that you can have access to all these commands.